# Decision path for a Random Forest Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is my code to run it in your environment, I am using the `RandomForestClassifier` and I am trying to figure out the `decision_path` for a selected sample in the `RandomForestClassifier`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50,
                               random_state=0)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The furthest I got is this:

```
#Extracting the decision path for instance i = 12
i_data = X_train.iloc[12].values.reshape(1,-1)
d_path = rf.decision_path(i_data)

print(d_path)
```

But the output doesn't make much sense:

> (<1x7046 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
> with 486 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, array([   0,  133,  282,  415,  588,  761,  910, 1041, 1182, 1309, 1432,
> 1569, 1728, 1869, 2000, 2143, 2284, 2419, 2572, 2711, 2856, 2987,
> 3128, 3261, 3430, 3549, 3704, 3839, 3980, 4127, 4258, 4389, 4534,
> 4671, 4808, 4947, 5088, 5247, 5378, 5517, 5640, 5769, 5956, 6079,
> 6226, 6385, 6524, 6655, 6780, 6925, 7046], dtype=int32))

I am trying to figure out the decision path for a particle sample in the dataframe. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

The idea is to have something like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RandomForestClassifier.decision_path` method returns a `tuple` of `(indicator, n_nodes_ptr)`. 
see the documentation : 
[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.decision_path)

So your variable `node_indicator` is a tuple and not what you think it is.
A tuple object has no attribute 'indices' that's why you get the error when you do :

```
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]
```

try :

```
(node_indicator, _) = rf.decision_path(X_train)
```

---

You can also plot the decision tree of each tree of the forest for a single sample id :

```
X_train = X_train.values

sample_id = 0

for j, tree in enumerate(rf.estimators_):

    n_nodes = tree.tree_.node_count
    children_left = tree.tree_.children_left
    children_right = tree.tree_.children_right
    feature = tree.tree_.feature
    threshold = tree.tree_.threshold

    print("Decision path for DecisionTree {0}".format(j))
    node_indicator = tree.decision_path(X_train)
    leave_id = tree.apply(X_train)
    node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                        node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]



    print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
    for node_id in node_index:
        if leave_id[sample_id] != node_id:
            continue

        if (X_train[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
            threshold_sign = "<="
        else:
            threshold_sign = ">"

        print("decision id node %s : (X_train[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
              % (node_id,
                 sample_id,
                 feature[node_id],
                 X_train[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
                 threshold_sign,
                 threshold[node_id]))
```

Note that in your case, you have 50 estimators so it might be a bit boring to read.

Comment: is it even possible to find the decision path for a random forest ?

Comment: yes, under the hood it combines the decision path of each tree in the forest

Comment: the problem is in the way we access the dataframe in the sample_id which i cant figure out

Comment: @arther also, we have not defined feature nor threshold, so there is no way your code works. please just delete the answer

Comment: i did not say my code work, i said it solved your initial error. the problem is that you apply a piece a code from here : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html which concern DecisionTreeClassifier to a RandomForestClassifier without changing anything ! After what I solved, you have to review the following of the code to make it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165434/discussion-between-arthur-and-victor).